# A question about tense agreement

Tags: tense, past-tense, sequence-of-tenses

Is the following sentence gramatically correct?

> I didn't understand what he wants to tell you.

I think that it expresses that at some time in the past I didn't understand what he still wants to tell you at the moment of speaking. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you are correct about how the tenses are being used.

It's more understandable if you put it in context:

> John's about to show up. He wants to tell you something. He discussed it with me a while ago. At first, ***I didn't understand what he wants to tell you.*** But now I do. You should hear him out and consider his words.

Barring that kind of context, it's certainly an unusual way of phrasing things. However, it's grammatical.

Comment: would this form also fit in this case i did not understand what he was going to tell you

Comment: @user5577 It's more easily understandable without additional context. *Did* and *was* are both past tense, so you don't need to think about it as much. (The *going to tell* part is future, but relative to the past time period.)